# How to derive a language when there is an unreachable non-terminal symbol?

Tags: context-free-grammar, formal-grammar

I have this formally defined grammar :

$$\begin{array}{rl}G=\langle&\{S,B,C\},\\&\{a,b,c\},\\&\{S\to CSB\mid CSa\mid a,B\to b\mid\epsilon,C\to c\},\\&S\rangle\end{array}$$

I know how to derive possible languages but, i have this question that i couldn't understand how to solve it because of non-terminal "$S$" symbol that exists in the right hand side:

> give the left derivation starting from S to the word $w_1=cccaab$, plus the derivation tree.

How do i deal with the $S$ since it is unreachable? It would be in the result which is false.
Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by  "$S$ is unreachable"? $S$ can produce one of $CSB$, $CSa$ or $a$. Not all of them contain $S$ again.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Yes, but i have to start with c to fulfill the requirement of the question. and in that C... there is an S

Comment: @StinkingBishop so how shall i start my derived language if i do not start it with S ? I have to start with S.

Comment: Derivation starts with $S$, but it doesn't mean that the *word* can't start with $c$. Take a simpler example: the word $cab$ is in $G$ because its derivation is $S\to CSB\underbrace{\to cSB}_{C\to c}\underbrace{\to caB}_{S\to a}\underbrace{\to cab}_{B\to b}$.

Comment: @StinkingBishop you derived 'a' from 'S' using which rule. It doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: There is a rule $S\to a$ if you look closely at your problem statement. There are six rules there: $S\to CSB, S\to CSa, S\to a, B\to b, B\to\epsilon, C\to c$.

Comment: @StinkingBishop aaah True. Thank you so much for that.